# How might I avoid significantly overestimating the time required to deliver a potential client's software project?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, clients, estimations, software-engineering

Spoke with a potential client about delivering a computer vision app. I estimated this would take one month, erring on the side of a conservative estimate to account for any complexities that might unexpectedly bubble up. However, I didn't realize just how conservative it was compared to another iOS engineer's estimate of 60-80 hours when he told me. He also said that a number of his contacts agreed that 60-80 hours sounds right.

How might I avoid such a discrepancy of 2-3x in the future, and potentially navigate situations like this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136135/discussion-on-question-by-austin-conlon-how-might-i-avoid-significantly-overesti).

Answer (score 160):

> I estimated this would take one month,

At this point into your text I was fully prepared to tell you how ridiculously short that timeframe is to develop an app on your own that does this. But it seems it was good I read your post till the end.

> He also said that a number of his contacts agreed that 60-80 hours sounds right.

Well, then let them do it on that estimate. When the 60-80 hour app isn't done in a few months and they are still paying by the hour, maybe they will remember you.

Your estimate was your estimate. If you feel like it was the truth then it doesn't matter what other people estimate. My former boss used to say "I could do this in VB over the weekend". Until one meeting I just got up and said "that's great, that way the development team can work on that other issue, just send it over on monday". I don't think he mentioned that stupid line ever again.

The only point you need to care about: could you have delivered on *your* estimate. Don't listen to other people. If other people estimate less, *they* should do it for/in less. You will find the willingness to estimate shorter will go up in smoke once you tell them that they will actually have to *do* it, not just talk about it.

So if someone says "but your competitor will do it for half", just say "that's great, I'm happy for you. Let me know if you have anything else you need help with."

Comment: Everything is easy if you are not the one who has to do it. I

Comment: Love the retort to the boss!

Comment: *When the app isn't done in a few months, maybe they will remember you* - They never do. I've never even heard of someone getting this kind of apology.

Comment: There is signifiant _politics_ involed in estimates when those estimates are used for anything other than planning start and end dates without pressure. Low estimates and low bids are sadly common practice when there is competition for work, and once started the client may have no recourse but to continue on an hourly rate to complete a project with the current hire, as they discover "unforseen complications" midway through the project. This also happens routinely enough without malice or any politics, so it is hard to tell the difference.

Comment: During sprint planning poker, a former manager would tell me that my estimates were "sandbagging" and that I could do the task in half the time. Well, I might be able to do it in half the time, maybe, but another team member might take more than twice my estimate. I tried to balance between "best time" and "worst case scenario", this is why it's called an estimate, because you really don't know how long it'll take until it's done.

Comment: legendary answer, absolutely spot on!

Comment: I'm going to go against the flow here and suggest that your retort the boss was not appropriate.  I've known many incredibly talented developers who can build in a day what takes others a week.  If one of them gets promoted to manager he may find himself irritated by the apparent slow pace.  However, working the weekend as a punishment for his talent/dedication is not a reasonable suggestion and not really his job either....

Comment: When OP mentions "computer vision" and "calculations ... body pose" I'd suggest 3D geometry is not in the normal developer's skillset. So yeah, OP's timeframe sounds short to me too.

Comment: @Mick I'm not sure what you mean, did I misuse terminology? The app uses pose detection like here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_human_body_poses_in_images, but I'm also being intentionally vague in the description to keep their exact idea secret.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri No, you won't get an apology, as certainly no apology is needed for taking the lower bid and discovering the party wasn't capable of delivering on time and on budget.  But many times I and people I've worked with in the consulting world have gotten calls months/years later when someone couldn't deliver.  No apology delivered or expected.  This is just sometimes how things go for everyone.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman The issue with the boss's comment is that it does nothing to further the discussion, is certainly unproductive, and it belittles the employees.  Being the best on the team at something by no means qualifies someone to be a manager, and this is a classic example of why (assuming he even is the most qualified person, which is rarely true in this situation).  Sure, the retort wasn't exactly mature or terribly constructive, but it probably got the point across just fine.  A manager has a duty to grow and empower his team, not make them feel inferior.

Comment: One way to grow and empower his team is to point out their weaknesses by showing them it can be done faster.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman pointing out that they can do it faster is not helpful even if true (often it's just wishful thinking), because it does not point out any actionable thing or correctable mistake but is pure bragging. It does not help the team to get better, and it does not help their motivation - quite on the contrary, it hurts morale. It is not a way to grow and empower the team because such an attitude is very disempowering.

Comment: @Peteris This is incorrect.  In many situations, simply knowing that a task can be done (in particular seeing it done by a peer) is significant motivation.

Comment: @AustinConlon No, and while I am not familiar with Apple's pose detection, computer vision is generally a complex topic, and working with 3D coordinate systems requires better than average mathematical skill, and increasingly so if precise measurements are required.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri It does happen, if rarely. My current employer once lost out on a big government contract (millions) because a competitor came in with a last minute offer a lot lower than ours. After a year the development of that was a right dumpster fire, the government considered it unsalvageable, cancelled the contract and gave it to the next company in line - us.

Answer (score 55):

1 month is about 150 hours, so you've estimated twice what another developer estimated. That is within the normal margin of error for software projects.

Unless you both independently develop this project you have no idea whose estimate will prove to be correct.

You can get a more accurate estimate by developing a more detailed spec, and then estimating the effort required for each part of the spec. However, this is likely to take a significant amount of effort in itself.

Comment: Honestly, with any software estimate, doubling/tripling it will usually give you the more accurate figure

Comment: The real knack is being able to tell _how many_ times to double it…

Comment: @Mirror318 I've always heard that you should double the numerical value of your estimate and go up to the next unit level. So if you think something will take 2 weeks, then you should say 4 months. https://lifehacker.com/estimate-how-much-time-you-need-for-a-project-then-dou-1592791225

Comment: @gidds There's a simple answer to that-  however many times you think you should double it, double that :)  The 2x and bump the units (so 2 hours becomes 4 days, etc)

Comment: @gidds "There is an art, or rather, a knack to estimating. The knack lies in learning how to throw yourself at a deadline and not miss. The first part is easy. All it requires is simply the ability to throw yourself forward with all your weight, and the willingness not to mind that it's going to hurt. That is, it's going to hurt if you fail to not miss the deadline. Most people fail to not miss the deadline, and if they are really trying properly, the likelihood is that they will fail to not miss it fairly hard. Clearly it is this second part, the not missing, which presents the difficulties."

Comment: over a 30+ year career," very best honest estimate" x 3 is historically accurate.

Answer (score 43):

> I didn't realize just how conservative it was compared to another iOS engineer's estimate of 60-80 hours when he told me

It's a common tactic to try and get estimates lessened to say someone else said it would take less. Yet they never seem to hire the person who said so. Because quite frequently they just pulled that estimate out of their backside or asked someone who pulled it from a similar place.

If you have the experience and knowledge to be sure of your estimates, stick to them. Otherwise you look greedy or incompetent.

> potentially navigate situations like this?

I would wish them good luck with their project and move forwards from their response if any.

Comment: Exactly, and then they will complain about why you went over your "corrected" estimate.

Comment: My company does a lot of fixed price software development. When we have customers ask about the price, rather than discussing the time estimated we discuss the insecurities that cause the estimate to grow. We are sometimes able to lower the price after clarifications or changes in the spec that simplifies our work and reduces risk.

Answer (score 19):

You can't avoid over-estimating or under-estimating the work, because there is no right answer. Your estimate must take into account  a lot of variables that you can't know in advance, and other quotes may include assumptions that you aren't comfortable with, or have a really low price because someone is desperate to get the work.

The key is to break the project down into sections, and assign time to each section. Then if the customer challenges your timings, you can justify the value, showing the elements that your competitors may have omitted. It also provides a framework for a bit of horse-trading, for example "As you can see, I've allocated 5 days for acceptance testing, but if you think that is too long, I can reduce it". Then if the testing takes more than the allotted time, you have some leverage to get a price increase.

The customer should get the impression that you have a standard system for calculating time & costs, and any variations you offer are carefully thought through. However, the reality is that most software project estimates include quite a bit of guesswork, so there is no right or wrong answer.

Comment: This reminds me of some house repairs I wanted done.  The first contractor walked around and listened to what I said needed to be done, then gave me a number.  The second contractor walked around, took notes, measured, and then sent me a detailed four page estimate with costs broken down.  Both came up with about the same number, but I went with the second: I could see that he wasn't overlooking anything I had mentioned.

Comment: There's definitely no right answer, but there are plenty of wrong answers. :-) Even if someone managed to estimate the correct time, they would still be wrong, due to the customer complaining about how long it is to accomplish, how expensive it is, how it's got "so many bugs" when it's done, how it doesn't look or work like they expected (even when they signed off on the look & feel), and so many other excuses.

Answer (score 16):

To avoid overestimation, here are my suggestions:

1. **Get input from experienced software engineers before giving the customers the estimated costs**

   If you work in a company with many experienced software engineers,
   then before you give the estimates to the customers, you can contact
   these experienced software engineers who have worked on **similar
   projects** to get some inputs or general guidelines.
2. **Who will actually work on the projects: experienced engineers or beginners ?**

   Please keep in mind that these experienced software engineers likely
   to have significant skills and therefore, it may take them much less
   time to complete the projects than the beginners.

   So, you will have to take into account whether the experienced engineers
   or beginners will actually write code for the project to get a
   better time estimate.
3. **The hiring costs : experienced engineers vs beginners:**

   You can also inform the customers about the costs. There is a tradeoff.

   It will cost more to hire an experienced engineer to complete a
   project in a short amount of time. The project may have less bugs
   and the design may look better.

   It may cost less to hire a beginner who may take longer to complete
   a project.

Comment: All the other answers are true, and I think address the real problem ... but this is the only one (I think) that attempts to answer the question as directly asked! +1

Comment: Another tip would be to do double blind estimates with a friend or colleague. You each estimate the work separately and then come together and compare. Discuss why one was lower/higher on a specific task and/or compare which tasks one person came up with that the other did not. Deciding on a basic set of tasks from the start usually makes this process easier.

Answer (score 8):

**If you can properly justify your estimate with sound reasoning, and show this to your client(s), then this is what matters most.**

What follows is a particular experience I had which, I hope, will help you understand the statement I just made - which is my answer to your question.

A few years ago, at a former employer, I had a team "lead", with a background in *mechanical* engineering, not *software* engineering, pitch his "solution" to upper management about how a problem could be solved with a "Simple System"™. The Simple System™ had to manage user accounts, track hardware inventory, notify specific users when certain component quantities were below a user-given threshold, allow users to place orders for more parts, produce reports, etc. - you know, the works. The estimate that *he* came up with for his "Simple System"™ was 3 months and *I* would be the one to do it. I said I thought it'd take longer than that.

I was basically asked to do a full project estimate - waterfall style[0]. So, this is what I did:

1. I spent about 2 weeks (that I could've spent working on the "Simple System"™) breaking down high-level feature requests all the way down to stories (with point estimates) and associated tasks.
2. I looked at my individual velocity per iteration in unrelated projects and used that as the basis for my assumed velocity on this estimate.
3. I did *not* estimate *time* - I estimated *effort* based on task size and then *derived* a time estimate from it (using velocity points per iteration, etc)
4. Documented a margin of error for the estimate. (This came from empirical data in the book *Agile Estimation and Planning*; **it shows an error margin between -40% and +60% *relative* to the original estimation value**.)

I explicitly documented the following assumptions:

1. estimates are *estimates*, *not commitments*;
2. waterfall-style estimates (which *they* asked for) are less reliable, need to be revisited *at least* every 6 months, and should be considered completely *invalid* if at least that much time has passed without a revision;
3. my degree of familiarity with the technologies that would be used in the project (i.e., I didn't have to spend time learning them from scratch).
4. I'm the only dev working on the system;
5. I have other responsibilities that will sometimes require that I stop working on "Simple System"™ (i.e., I'm not working on "Simple System"™ 100% of my time without interruptions)
6. That velocity-based estimates were based on *unrelated* projects and may be different in practice. (In reality, velocity is a measure for a *team, not individuals*)
7. The estimate was only as good as the documented assumptions - break the assumptions, and you invalidate the estimate.

Long story short, my estimate came to **15 *months*** to implement all the features, with the -40%+60% margin being down to **9 months** (best case) and up to **24 months** (worst case). (**NOTE:** This was 15 months to complete all features, not 15 months before we could have a portion of the system up and running in production while making incremental improvements.) They didn't like my estimate, so what was their solution? *They delegated the project to an inexperienced intern and **invalidated** the whole estimate instead.* After all, the intern was expected to be around for up to a year and they knew for a Fact™ that building Simple System™ wasn't going to take more than 3 months, so they could go overtime 4x over without it being a problem, right? **GENIUS!** (No, I'm not joking.)

The first Git commit in the Simple System™ repo was April 29th, 2014. For whatever reason, my brain committed that snapshot into its own memory and remembers. I had made that commit.

Well, fast forward 7 months and it seems reality is starting to rear its ugly head back at them. My manager, the very person who made the decision to hand it off to an intern, made a comment saying "Well, no one's talking about the Simple System™ project estimates anymore..."[1]. I just gave her my I-tried-to-tell-you-shrug and kept going. It was their own self-inflicted problem, not mine.

Fast forward again. It's been a year. The intern left for another team. They brought a new *inexperienced* intern to work on the previous intern's codebase[2].

Fast forward yet again. It's been at least 1.5 years since work on Simple System™ had started. It's June 30th, 2016 and it's my last day at the company. Simple System™ still had *zero* working releases *in production* - not even a partial one.

A friend close to the project within the same team at the company told me it took them about 7-9 more months to make a first release - and there were still lots of missing features.

**If you're doing the work, then it's your estimate, based on your knowledge, experience, and ability.** If you can show sound reasoning to your clients on *why* you're estimating something in a particular way, then that may or may not help. You could explain that you're trying to account for some unforeseen events and that, if things go smoothly, you'd expect things to take less time overall, and so on.

Keep in mind that some tend to provide their "best-case" estimates, *assuming* nothing goes terribly wrong - since it might be unlikely - and then, as soon as something worth mentioning does happen, they inform the client of the delay and adjust the estimate. At the end of the day, client assumes that particular risk.

Also, keep in mind that you have no idea about how others have justified their own estimates - if at all? Perhaps they've solved that kind of problem so many times they already have enough experience to know how much work that is "by heart". Perhaps they have more people. Perhaps they're full of crap. It's up to the client to weigh in those factors.

---

[0] I argued against this, but it was a waste of time.

[1] While this is speculation, I took this to mean that Mr "lead" and Mrs manager had been, basically, trashing my original estimate behind my back in their pRoGrEsS mEeTiNgS, and how I (in their view) had no idea what I was saying/doing/etc, prior to that point or whatever. (Note that no one ever bothered to challenge the *reasoning and justifications* behind my estimate, but that's probably beside the point. As far as I could tell, they just "felt" Simple System™ was Simple Enough™ to take 3 months because they kept referring to Simple System™ as "simple".)

[2] When I say inexperienced, neither knew Python, SQL for databases, how client-server systems worked, Django, Git, Apache, etc. They were computer *engineering* majors, not computer *science* majors, so I don't blame them.

Comment: +1  I read your 1 paragraph description and esitmated 18 months for an experienced developer .........

Comment: There’s a crucial point buried here that should be emphasized: “If you can show sound reasoning to your clients on why you’re estimating something in a particular way, then that may or may not help.” The “may help” is your answer — by giving a detailed account of the work required, you reveal your competitors pitching 60-80 hours as being optimistic (charitable) or disingenuous or incompetent (not unlikely). That helps build trust between you and the prospective client. Ultimately, getting a contract is as much about the numbers adding up correctly as it is about the numbers being realistic.

Comment: And with respect to the “may not”, this reality check works as a filter — if the prospective client sees a pitch that includes a detailed analysis and decides to go with a rosy, mushy pitch instead…well, you’ve just saved yourself from the stress of multiple hard conversations and a likely unreasonable, ultimately dissatisfied, client.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this as a new answer, though it sort of just refutes the original assumption.  You said,

> How might I avoid such a discrepancy of 2-3x in the future, and potentially navigate situations like this?

How do you know you have a discrepancy? You are not the same as your developer buddies. If someone asks me how long it will take to do a project, and the project is highly similar to one that I already have a code-base to handle, then the project could conceivably be done in days, not weeks or months. If you asked me how long to do a project that isn't similar to other work I've done, then it might take me a month while others could do it in half a month.

Having a large code-base to pull code snippets from is half of the benefit of having experience. The other half is in knowing pitfalls before you hit them, so that you can discuss them with the client before it causes your development to grind to a halt.

Answer (score 3):

Software **always** takes longer than estimated.  I recommend an estimating technique an experienced IT person explained to me a long time ago:  (1) calculate your best estimate based on your experience and carefully researching the problem, (2) **double your estimate**, (3) present it with plus/minus 25% to cover contingencies.  For example, if after careful consideration you think a project will take 100 hours, predict 200 hours plus/minus 50 hours.  If someone estimates less, wish them the best and move on.  And if your estimate is accepted, always announce as soon as possible when the schedule has to change because something new (typically a spec change) has been introduced.

Comment: There are some exceptions to the "always" – sometimes a problem looks more complicated than it actually is, and on starting to implement it you might discover an easier way of doing it. But of course, you can't calculate with this.

Comment: This basically says that the software engineering profession is incompetent. And it’s simply not true.

Comment: In one place I worked, we routinely did post partem analysis, comparing estimates with actuals and determining how/why they differed. After you’ve done this for a few years, you understand how mistakes are made, and you can avoid them.

Comment: I strongly recommend this very simplified approach because it doesn't give you insight into all the things that could go wrong.  Instead, after estimating best-case, try to think of all the ways you can shoot holes in that estimate.  "What if they meant Y but said X?  What if Y, Z, or V?"  Then estimate worst-case after you've really shaken some rotten fruit from the tree (maybe with help).  The projects that go woefully over-budget are the ones where the worst- and best-case estimates are really far apart.  2x is generally the closest they ever are together (IMHO).

Comment: Also look at PERT or 3-point estimation.  Very effective as a simple, easy-to-get-started-with tool.

Answer (score 3):

I think the big problem is that they appear to be tying hours of work directly to days in a week which isn't accurate.

> However, I didn't realize just how conservative it was compared to another iOS engineer's estimate of 60-80 hours when he told me. He also said that a number of his contacts agreed that 60-80 hours sounds right.

If you break that down it would be 7.5 to 10 days of work. However that would only be the case if you are working on this 8 hours a day with nothing else involved. If you factor in things such as emails or meetings with the client the amount of time you can focus on the work decreases. If you factor in any other work that might come up during that time it will reduce the work you can get done even further.

When doing an estimate you shouldn't just focus on the amount of time it will take to do the code but also how much time you will be able to devote to it on a given day. From my perspective saying 60-80 hours of work and 1 month of time to deliver the product isn't that far off as you can easily spend those hours over 3 or 4 weeks instead of the 2 that the hours alone would suggest.

Not to mention a common thing that non developers tend to forget is that 2 different people can write the same program in a vastly different length of time based on their experience with what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I didn't realize just how conservative it was compared to another iOS engineer's estimate of 60-80 hours when he told me.

I'm sorry, but this question sounds naive. Imagine that you're about to run a marathon for the very first time, and you think you can complete it in 5 hours. You don't suddenly change your estimate because you hear someone else can complete it in 2 hours. That would be insane.

> He also said that a number of his contacts agreed that 60-80 hours sounds right.

Next time, ask questions. Ask to see the paper trail. If there was no paper trail to speak of, and no written estimate, assume that the spec was full of holes and that the calculation was for a barebones prototype.

In other words, you should be multiplying that estimate by a factor of 9 (according to [Fred Brooks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201835959)) instead of reducing it.

But most importantly, you should be asking many-many questions. How come was the other estimate so low? Were they going to use a commercial SDK? Is a commercial SDK allowed? Is there a licensing budget for that? Did they do that kind of project before? Does the company have a reputation for delivering on their estimates? How many other projects have they done for them?

And if you still don't understand why their estimate was so low, assume the worst. Because whatever magic sauce they do have, you don't have it yourself. After all, not everyone can run a marathon in two hours, and that's ok.